# How to fix dictionary out-of-range error in "XOR"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xor

I'm trying to encrypt using python's "XOR" method. I use my dictionary and apply this algorithm:

```
def crypt(Line,key):
   alpha = ' !@#^*()_+"№;:?-={}[]\|/<>.,~`1234567890zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAяюэьыъщшчцхфутсрпонмлкйизжёедгвбаЯЮЭЬЫЪЩШЧЦХФУТСРПОНМЛКЙИЗЖЁЕДГВБА'
   new_Line = ''
   for i in range(len(Line)):
        code = alpha.find(Line[i]) ^ alpha.find(key[i])
        new_Line += alpha[code]
   return new_Line
```

But when I try to encrypt the characters: "П", "ъ" I get a value of 236, which exceeds the length of my dictionary, since it only has 158 characters. How to fix the error would be that the code decode unambiguously. At the moment, there is an idea to expand the dictionary (alpha).

Comment: A typical way to solve this is to encode the text to UTF-8 and encrypt the bytes which have a defined range of 0 - 255.

Comment: @klaus-d, ok, but how do I fix my code to work with a given dictionary?